# Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined in HTML,

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I solve this?

My JSON data coming from an API is causing this error:

> ERROR in src/app/weather/weather.component.ts(39,30): error TS2339: Property 'main' does not exist on type 'Iweather[]'

JSON:

```
{
  "main": {
    "temp": 28,
    "feels_like": 32.95,
    "temp_min": 28,
    "temp_max": 28,
    "pressure": 1008,
    "humidity": 78
  }    
}
```

I was unable to use JSON data in HTML .

My interface is:

```
    export interface IWeather {
        name : string;
        main: any[];
    }
```

My services.ts:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import { Iweather } from './Data-Interface';


    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class WeatherServiceService {

      constructor( private http : HttpClient) { }

      getRequest(val) : Observable<Iweather[]>{
        let APP_ID ="myAPICode";
        let cityName = val;
        let url ='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName + '&units=metric&appid=' + APP_ID;
         return this.http.get<Iweather[]>(url);
      }
    }
```

My component part:

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
      import { WeatherServiceService } from '../weather-service.service';
      import { Iweather } from '../Data-Interface';
      import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
      @Component({
        selector: 'app-weather',
        templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./weather.component.css']
      })
      export class WeatherComponent implements OnInit {

        options: FormGroup;
        floatLabelControl = new FormControl('auto');
        constructor(private WeatherService : WeatherServiceService , fb: FormBuilder) { 
          this.options = fb.group({
            floatLabel: this.floatLabelControl
          });
        }

        public weatherData : Iweather[] = [];

        ngOnInit() {}

        public cityName ="";
        public Status = "true";
        public humidity = "";
        public pressure = "";
        public wind_speed = "";
        public weather = "";
        public temp :string;

        getWeatherReport(value) {
          this.Status = 'false';
          this.cityName =value;
          this.WeatherService.getRequest(this.cityName)
          .subscribe((data : Iweather[]) => {
            this.temp = data.main.temp;
            this.humidity = data.main.humidity;
            this.pressure = data.main.pressure;
            this.weatherData = data;
          }); 
        }
      }
```

My HTML:

```
       {{ weatherData.name }}
```

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Many problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is two options to solve this :

1) replace this.temp = data.main by this.temp = data["main"] 
or

2) create an interface :

```
export interface Iweather {
    main: {
    temp: number,
    feels_like: number,
    temp_min: number,
    temp_max: number,
    pressure: number,
    humidity: number
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been stuck I this for last 3 Days.

Comment: It worked but can you explain why we need brackets and double quotes for this.

Comment: when you try to access to a property with a dot, it means you already have this property (in your case: main), you can use dot if you create an interface with these properties that you are trying to access.
but in javascript, if you access via brackets and double quotes it means if it finds this property ok  good otherwise it will create it

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable is an array of `Iweather` interface, you are trying to reach `main` property directly from array in your subscribe method. You should loop through its elements with `foreach` or use a specific index like `data[0]` to reach the main property.

```
.subscribe((data : Iweather[]) => {
        //since you need single day you don't need to loop
        this.temp = data[0].main.temp; 
        this.humidity = data[0].main.humidity;
        this.pressure = data[0].main.pressure;
        //Here you declatred weatherData as IWeather[] array so i'm not changing that.
        this.weatherData = data;
      });
```

Edit: I edited the code block above. Since you receive and also need single day's wheater you don't need to use loop through the `data`. You only need to get the first `IWeather` element's `main` property.

Comment: Can you explain how to use foreach for this.

Comment: Actually, to give a better answer, i need to know more about what is going on.
Why you receive Iweather[] as array from API, is it wheather of multiple days? What do you plan to show on front-end, wheather of a single day?

Comment: Weather for single day.. I have bind the observables to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is: in your interface property 'main' is array. But in API response it is an Object and not array.
You can create a model object(lets say MyData.model.ts) for 'main' object and then use it in interface as 
main: MyData[];
If you are sure that only one object of main is returned from API response, you can use index [0] in code for fetching it or else use foreach loop.